# How to make JMETER make 166 requests in 1 second?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, stress-testing

I need to make stress testing for some service and I need to make 10 000 requests.
How to make correctly 166 requests in 1 second ?
Have I made correct settings below ? (picture below)
[image]

Comment: You should set threads to 166 and RampUp Period to 1 and you can set loop count according to 10000/166 = 61.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make 166 requests in 1 second and stop here is the relevant [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) setup:

[image]

If you want to make 166 requests per second for 1 minute resulting in 9960 requests it's better to consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) configured like:

[image]

in that case it makes sense to use [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) which can be connected to the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter could kick off extra threads if the current amount is not enough to conduct the necessary number of requests per second

Comment: Yes I want to make 166 requests during 1 min. What kind of settings should I put to Concurrency Thred Group ? 
Target Concurrency: ... , 
Ramp up Time(sec):... ,
 Ramp-Up Steps Count: ... ,
 Hold Target Rate Time: ... ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a new thread group.
2. Add 166 threads as thread count.
3. Add 1 sec as Rampup time.
4. Set looping condition as 1.
5. Then Implement the HTTP request and run the test